# How to read a very large dataset from an HDF5 file?

Tags: c, hdf5

I've started learning HDF5 API very recently. Suppose that I'm going to read a very large vector (i.e. one-dimentional array) which is stored as a dataset in an HDF5 file. Its size `N_SIZE` is so large that `malloc(N_SIZE)` fails. So it seems to me that I have to read it chunk by chunk. Should I use `H5Dread_chunk()` here?

Comment: Well, try it. We all learn by trying, less by asking. ;-)

Comment: A good start is [Hierarchical Data Format - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) followed by [HDF5 Tutorial: Learning The Basics Reading from and Writing to a Dataset (c-example)](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/rdwt.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will have to read the dataset chunk by chunk if it does not fit in main memory. Also, please note that your dataset must be created with a chunked storage layout. Then you can read one chunk at the time using hyperslabs (i.e. slices).

All these can be greatly simplified with [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com). HDFql is a high-level language that alleviates you from the low-level details of handling HDF5 files.

As an example, you could do the following in C using HDFql:

```
// declare variables
char script[100];
int data[1024][1024];
int i;

// create a HDF5 file named 'my_file.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
hdfql_execute("CREATE AND USE FILE my_file.h5");

// create a three dimensional chunked dataset named 'my_dataset' (each chunk is 1 MB)
hdfql_execute("CREATE CHUNKED(1, 1024, 1024) DATASET my_dataset AS INT(100, 1024, 1024)");

// register variable 'data' for subsequent usage
hdfql_variable_register(data);

// loop 100 times (i.e. number of chunks that exists in dataset 'my_dataset')
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    // prepare script to read one chunk at the time using an hyperslab
    sprintf(script, "SELECT FROM my_dataset[%d:::1] INTO MEMORY 0", i);

    // execute script
    hdfql_execute(script);

    // call hypothetical function 'process' passing variable 'data' that contains the chunked data
    process(data);
}
```

Additional examples on how to use HDFql in C can be found [here](http://www.hdfql.com/examples).

Comment: What if the dataset is not created with a chunked storage layout? Then, is `H5Dread()` the only way to read data?

Comment: If the dataset was not created with a chunked storage layout, you can still use functions meant for chunking and hyperslabs. The issue with this is that since the dataset does not have a chunked storage layout, the HDF5 library will have to read the entire dataset (which is not good in terms of performance in case you are just interested in a certain chunk - or few of them - of the dataset).

Comment: Thanks @SOG. I understand why only datasets with chunked storage layout are extensible. But as a programmer, it's not obvious to me why the entire dataset has to be read in order to access, say, a few bytes, when the storage layout is contiguous.

Comment: I understand your perspective but, AFAIK, this is how the HDF5 library behaves (i.e. the dataset has to be entirely read when its storage layout is not chunked even accessing few bytes). Maybe other people can provide additional info/feedback in case the library actually do behave differently.